# Creating a line counter using a Binary Search Tree **Specific Issues**

Tags: c, linux, binary-search-tree

I want to create a C file which, via a binary-search-tree, reads from a text file, takes its identifiers (eg.include, stdio, hello, etc.), sorts them alphabetically, and returns what line number they appear on.

**Desired terminal output:**

> Identifier: Hello
>
> Counter: 2
>
> Lines Appeared: [4, 6]

**Issues:**

1. *q1.c:28:21: error: expected expression before '{' token*
   28 | n -> lineList = {};
2. *When calling insert(), for the current Node, I want to add the current lineNumber to the tree->lineList[tree->counter-1].*

**test.txt**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    printf("Lochlann\n");
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

**quetion.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <ctype.h>

struct Node {
    char * data;
    int lineList[100];
    int counter;
    struct Word * word;
    struct Node * ltree;
    struct Node * rtree;
};

struct Node * head;

struct Node * newTree(char * identifier) {
    struct Node * n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    n -> data = malloc(strlen(identifier) + 1);
    n -> lineList = {};
    n -> counter = 1;
    strcpy(n -> data, identifier);
    n -> ltree = n -> rtree = NULL;
    return n;
}

struct Node * insert(struct Node * tree, char * identifier, int lineNumber) {
    if (tree == NULL)
        return newTree(identifier);
    int cmp = strcmp(identifier, tree -> data);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        tree -> counter++;
        tree -> lineList[tree -> counter - 1] = lineNumber;
        return tree;
    }

    if (cmp < 0)
        tree -> ltree = insert(tree -> ltree, identifier, lineNumber);
    else
        tree -> rtree = insert(tree -> rtree, identifier, lineNumber);
    return tree;
}

void inorder(struct Node * tree) {
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    inorder(tree -> ltree);

    printf("Identifier: %s\nCounter: %i\nLines Appeared: ", tree -> data, tree -> counter);
    for (int i = 0; i < tree -> counter; i++) {
        printf("%d", tree -> lineList[i]);
        //tree -> lineList[i] = lineNumber;
    }
    printf("\n");

    inorder(tree -> rtree);
}

main() {
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    char buf[200];
    char id[100];
    int lineNumber = 1; //the tree->lineList should be [1,1,1,1,1,1]
    int j;
    while (fgets(buf, 100, fp)) {
        int i = 0;
        int len = strlen(buf);
        for (j = 0, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (isalpha(buf[i]) || buf[i] == '_') {
                while (buf[i] && (isalnum(buf[i]) || buf[i] == '_'))
                    id[j++] = buf[i++];

                // have id
                id[j] = 0;

                //third argument adding line to linelist
                head = insert(head, id, lineNumber);

                j = 0;
            }

        }

    }
    inorder(head);
}
```

Comment: _Side note:_ Novice: `x -> y` Experienced: `x->y`

Comment: OT: `for (int i = 0; i < tree -> counter; i++)` How will you handle the 3 appearances of `i`' on this one line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to explain the problem more directly. Instead of saying "there are specific issues" in the question title, directly ask about **one of** them. Also keep in mind that we expect one question at a time here. If there is a compiler error, then nothing about the code functionality can be properly considered until that is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With little else on the go, here's a "mark-up" of your code. Please consider some / most / all of these comments for this program and for others.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct Node {
    char * data; // "generic" name. "token" might be better.
    int lineList[100]; // limited, but okay for now
    int counter;
//  struct Word * word; // unused. keep things clean.
    struct Node * ltree;
    struct Node * rtree;
};

struct Node * head; // global variables are not recommended

struct Node * newTree(char * identifier, int lnNum ) {
//  struct Node * n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node * n = calloc( 1, sizeof *n ); // use calloc
    /* omitting test for NULL */

    n -> data = malloc(strlen(identifier) + 1);
    /* omitting test for NULL */
    strcpy(n -> data, identifier); // do this here

//  n -> lineList = {}; // unnecessary with calloc

    n->lineList[ n->counter++ ] = lnNum; // missing!!!
    // with calloc(), counter starts at zero

//  strcpy(n -> data, identifier); // shifted to where used
//  n -> ltree = n -> rtree = NULL; // unnecessary with calloc
    return n;
}

struct Node * insert(struct Node * tree, char * identifier, int lineNumber) {
    if (tree == NULL)
        return newTree(identifier, lineNumber ); // missing param linenumber!
    int cmp = strcmp(identifier, tree -> data);
    if (cmp == 0) {
//      tree -> counter++;
//      tree -> lineList[tree -> counter - 1] = lineNumber;

        /* omitting test for overrun */
        tree -> lineList[ tree->counter ] = lineNumber;
        tree->counter++;
        return tree;
    }

    if (cmp < 0)
        tree -> ltree = insert(tree -> ltree, identifier, lineNumber);
    else
        tree -> rtree = insert(tree -> rtree, identifier, lineNumber);
    return tree;
}

void inorder(struct Node * tree) {
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    inorder(tree -> ltree);

    printf("Identifier: %s\nCounter: %i\nLines Appeared: ", tree -> data, tree -> counter);
    for (int i = 0; i < tree -> counter; i++) {
        printf("%d", tree -> lineList[i]);
        //tree -> lineList[i] = lineNumber;
    }
    printf("\n");

    inorder(tree -> rtree);
}

int main() { // proper declaration of 'main()'
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r"); // fewer lines
    /* omitting test for success */

    char buf[200];
//  char id[100]; // not needed yet
    int lineNumber = 0; // got zero lines so far
//  int j; // willy-nilly variables
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) { // compiler knows dimensions
        lineNumber++; // missing!

        int len = strlen(buf);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; /* i++ */) { // let body decide
            if (isalpha(buf[i]) || buf[i] == '_') {
                int j = 0; // NOW we need 'j' and..
                char id[100];

                while (buf[i] && (isalnum(buf[i]) || buf[i] == '_'))
                    id[j++] = buf[i++]; // here, 'i' is left on next character

                // have id
                id[j] = '\0'; // same, but conventional

                //third argument adding line to linelist
                head = insert(head, id, lineNumber);

                // j = 0; // don't care about j anymore
            }
            else i++;
        }
    }
    inorder(head);

    return 0; // optional with newer compilers
}
```

You could even consider 'ditching' the copying of tokens from one buffer to another. Here's a slightly tighter for() loop for `main()`:

```
for( int i = 0; buf[ i ]; i++ )
    if (isalpha(buf[i]) || buf[i] == '_') {
        int tokStart = i;
        while (buf[i] && (isalnum(buf[i]) || buf[i] == '_'))
            i++; // find end of token (or line)

        char c = buf[i]; // remember this character
        buf[i] = '\0'; // clobber it
        head = insert(head, buf + tokStart, lineNumber);
        buf[i--] = c; // restore character AND decrement
    }
```

Comment: This is a great follow-along explanation. Thank you, I now understand the concept much more :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. q1.c:28:21: error: expected expression before '{' token 28 | n -> lineList = {};

The problematic code is cited right there in the error message.  The immediate issue is that the line is syntactically incorrect, because `{}` does not represent an assignable value of any type.  But underneath that, you have a deeper problem: C arrays are not assignable in the first place.  You can assign to array *elements*, but not to whole arrays.

There is a variety of functions you could use, such as `memset()` or `memcpy()`, but in this case, your best bet might be to perform the allocation of `n` with `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.  One of the distinctions between these is that `calloc()` initializes the allocated memory to all-bytes-zero.

> 2. When calling insert(), for the current Node, I want to add the current lineNumber to the tree->lineList[tree->counter-1].

Considering that C array indexes start at 0, not 1, I guess you want to do that *before* incrementing the node's counter. You are instead doing it *after*, when `counter` has a value one larger.  Personally, though, I would start the counter for each node at 0 instead of at 1, and then do this on insertion:

```
        tree->lineList[tree->counter++] = lineNumber;
```

That uses the value of the counter as of entry to the function as the index into `lineList`, and also increments the counter so that the next line number will go into the next position.